# How do I manually set location for redshift using the conf files?

Tags: redshift, geolocation

I have geolocation turned off in Ubuntu 15.10. Is there a way to set location via GPS coordinates or neatest metro area using the in `~/.config/redshift.conf`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you can add the following to the config, where `lat` is your latitude and `lon` is your longitude. You can find these for example using google maps. Just right click anywhere on the map and choose "What's here?" from the menu.

```
[redshift]
location-provider=manual

[manual]
lat=48.1
lon=11.6
```

Additional info in [this archwiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Redshift#Manual_setup).